# Not able to delete PDF ebook in BookWorm

Tags: applications

I'm obviously missing something, but when I select an ebook, it opens in BookWorm. But when I want to select it to be deleted, it just opens the ebook:

- Left click on ebook just opens it.
- Clicking on the `-` button and then on the ebook also opens it.

Clearly not one of my brighter moments - is this a bug or am I just in need of coffee? :)

Here's a GIF of what I'm doing (click for full-size):

[image: animated screenshot]

Comment: Came across this today...the right sequence for deletion is to first select the books by clicking on the tick icon on the bottom and then clicking on the - icon on the bottom bar.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a 3rd party app and not an app that elementary develops, you probably should open an issue report in [Bookworm's tracker](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/issues) since it looks like [their wiki](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/wiki) is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is an User Experience issue.

[image]

The good news is: it works.
The bad news: It's freakin' confusing.